# How to temporarily deactivate all try / catch blocks?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a possibility to deactivate / activate all try catch blocks in the whole project as easy as clicking a button?

I need this for debugging when I don't want the catch block to handle the exception, but instead prefer that VS breaks into the code as if the try catch block was not there.

At the moment I am commenting out the try/catch blocks but this is inefficient.

Environment: VS 2008 with C# as language.

Comment: What is the purpose? why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why are you guys so disturbed about somebody asking a question? If you wait five minutes, you'll see if somebody comes up with a useful answer than you had not anticipated.

Comment: The purpose is for debugging to fix the error by having Visual Studio stop where the error happened.

Answer (score 43):

To catch exceptions the moment they're thrown ("first-chance exceptions" in Win32 parlance):

- in VS2008: go to **Debug**, **Exceptions...**
- by VS2015: this has been moved to **Debug > Windows > Exception Settings**

Then check the box **Thrown** for **Common Language  Runtime Exceptions**.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is exactly what OP wanted to achieve by disabling all try catches.

Answer (score 17):

There is no way to deactivate try/catch blocks.

However, for debug purposes, if you want to break as soon as a particular type of exception is thrown, you can get Visual Studio to do that (Debug -> Exceptions; select the exception type you're interested in and check the "Thrown" box).

Comment: I have a reason: Having heavy error message suppression (client is allergic to all kinds of .net error page) and I need to debug a page during development of an additional section couple months later.

Comment: This is admittedly probably an edge case, but I'm in the situation right now where I have to develop against both Excel 2007 and 2013 in the same codebase, which means I have to use VS2012.  That also means my debugging against Excel 2013 has to be with compiled code because VS 2012 won't attach to Excel 2013 for debugging.  I'd love to quickly disable my try/catch blocks right now...

Comment: @squillman: It's entirely unclear to me what "developing against Excel 2007 and 2013" has to do with disabling try/catch blocks...

Comment: Yeah, I definitely could have explained that better.  I have an add-in that needs to work in both 2007 and 2013 so I have to develop in VS2012.  I have an exception getting thrown but only in Excel 2013 which I can't debug with.  Crappily coded catch blocks are making it difficult to find what and where the real exception is...

Comment: But again, edge case and probably not a good argument for R# or anyone to make a Disable Try/Catch feature anytime soon.

Answer (score 4):

Thought about this today and found an other solution. The advantage of this is that the IDE will stop at the exact point of the occuring exception.

Somewhere globaly defined:

```
Namespace Global.System
  Public Class NeverOccurException
    Inherits Exception
  End Class
End Namespace
```

At the beginning of each source code file:

```
#If DEBUG
  Imports CatchAtReleaseException = System.NeverOccurException
#Else
  Imports CatchAtReleaseException = System.Exception
#End If
```

Usage:

```
  'Compiled in DEBUG-Mode the TryCatch is "disabled", because the
  'the ALIAS CatchAtReleaseException is set to "NeverOccurException"

  'Compiled as RELEASE the TryCatch is "enabled", because the ALIAS
  'is set to the regular "System.Exception"

  Public Sub SampleSub()
    Try
      '...
    Catch ex As CatchAtReleaseException
    End Try
  End Sub
```

Have fun with it,
Greetings,
Ted

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do in the IDE, Debug -> Exceptions is the dialog where you can ask the IDE to break when a specific/category/all exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way Visual Studio breaks when an exception occurs. By default, it breaks on unhandled exceptions. If you go to menu Debug > Exceptions, you can uncheck Common Language Runtime Exceptions and make other changes in the IDE's behavior when exceptions occur. For example, you can have it break on only one kind of exception; there's a long list there.

I have done this on rare occasions when trying to debug.